# Is it possible to change the default initial field value via reflection in java?

Tags: java, reflection, field

lets say we have a class with an field and it has a default initial value and that is not changed by the constructor, for example

```
public class Server {
  private int pingFrequency = 500;

  public Server() {
  }
}
```

Now I want't to change the default initial value to another value **BEFORE** the object is constructed. The reason is that this class is used by an library and hide away the object instance. So I could only control when the object is constructed but not where and how.

I've tried to get field via reflection, but I dont't see any way to change the default value

```
Field pingFrequency =  Class.forName("Server").getDeclaredField("pingFrequency")
```

I think I must change something in the classloader, but I don't know what and how.

Thank you

Comment: you cannot do that, because your field is a private field, not static. You can only change that if you create an object. But anyway this looks like a not very nice design.

Comment: Your best bet is probably a [Java Agent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) that changes the bytecode of the Server class.

Comment: But somewhere the information which value should be used as default must be stored. It would be interesting where it is and how to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a class like

```
public class Server {
  private int pingFrequency = 500;

  public Server() {
  }
}
```

it is not different to

```
public class Server {
  private int pingFrequency;

  public Server() {
    pingFrequency = 500;
  }
}
```

or

```
public class Server {
  private int pingFrequency;

  {
    pingFrequency = 500;
  }
  public Server() {
  }
}
```

In fact, all three variants get compiled to identical bytecode. The code of all field initializers and instance initializer blocks gets copied to every constructor¹ of this class, right between the super constructor call and the rest of the constructor. [[JLS §12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5-220)]
<sub>¹ which does not delegate to another constructor of this class</sub>

The only way to change the assigned value is do modify the code of all constructors, to change the assignment. This can not be done via Reflection, but only via bytecode manipulation tools.

Note that when the field has been declared `final`, like

```
public class Server {
  private final int pingFrequency = 500;

  public Server() {
  }
}
```

there will be an attribute in the bytecode, reporting the constant value [[JVMS §4.7.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.2)], *additionally* to the assignment. However, for such a compile-time constant, every ordinary read access will be replaced with the constant value at compile-time[[JLS §13.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1-110-C)], so even changing the assignment would have no effect then (neither would changing the attribute)[[JLS §13.4.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9-200)]. Trying to replace the actual uses of the field would raise the problem that you can’t distinguish them from other uses of the constant number `500`.

If the field was `static` and `final`, there was no assignment at all, the constant value attribute would be used for initializing the field, however, changing it would have as little effect as for a constant instance field, as the field accesses were still replaced with the old constant value.